# JAXB Unmarshal: Set same attribute value to two model class properties

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, unmarshalling, moxy

XML root Element has an id attribute with the value something like

```
<Party id="PARTYID_1341592540748_ed044bd3-b8b2-40f9-a679-4daa411ecc45">
```

Here I need complete PartyId and a part of it in two different variables. I am trying to achieve it like this:

```
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String id;// complete partyId

    @XmlTransient
    @XmlAttribute(name="id")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(PartyIdAdapter.class) //has logic to trim full party Id
    protected String partyId; //sub partyId
```

But I always get null for String partyId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally achieved it with the help of third variable:

```
@Id
    protected Long elementPK;

    protected String completeId;

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setId(String value)
    {
        this.completeId = value; 
        this.elementPK = Long.parseLong(value.split("_")[1]); 
    }
```

If you can come up with an elegant solution then please let me know.